# How to manage multiple environments on Azure DevoOps for React JS application

Tags: reactjs, azure-devops, deployment, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to set up a CI/CD pipeline in Azure DevOps for a React application, and I'm facing challenges managing multiple environments using secure files. I've followed the setup from [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/mail4hafij/react_azure_devops_pipeline) and would appreciate some guidance.

Problem Description:-
1] I have a sample environment file (refer image below) used during the 'npm run build' command.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PNdA.png)

I've uploaded this file to Azure Pipelines Library as a secure file as shown here.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puh9u.png)

In my package.json, the build command is configured as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8Mj6.png)

Finally, I've created a YAML script that should download the .env file from the secure library and use the variables during the build. The script is as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYK3K.png)

I'm seeking advice on how to effectively manage multiple environments with the same CI/CD pipeline. Is there a way to pass different environment variables for different environments within the same pipeline?

Any guidance or suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

I am very new to CI-CD set up for ReactJS using Azure Devops.

Comment: Do you encounter any errors during the execution of the pipeline? From your screenshot, the .env file is a file without related value, Do you mean that you want to pass the pipeline variables to the .env file when deploying to different environments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your screenshots, you are using the `.env file` and the command `env-cmd -r development`.

Refer to this site: [env-cmd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/env-cmd)

> -r, --rc-file [path]                Custom rc file path (default path: ./.env-cmdrc(|.js|.json)

> -e, --environments [env1,env2,...]  The rc file environment(s) to use

Based on your situation, you can modify the `.env` file name to `.env-cmdrc.json`.

Then you can change the npm command from `env-cmd -r development npm run-script build` to `env-cmd -e development npm run-script build` in Package.json.

For example:

.env-cmdrc.json file:

```
{
 "development":{
 "REACT_APP_BASE_URL": "https://servername:port/"
 },
 "qa":{
 "REACT_APP_BASE_URL": "http://servername:port/"
 },
  "local":{
  "REACT_APP_BASE_URL": "http://localhost:port/"
  }
 }
```

Package.json:

```
"build-dev": "env-cmd -e development npm run-script build"
```

In Azure DevOps Pipeline, you can add multiple YAML stages to manage multiple environments.

For example:

```
stages:
- stage: development
  jobs:
  - job: development
    steps:
      - task: NodeTool@0
        inputs:
          versionSpec: '16.x'
        displayName: 'Install Node.js'


      # Download secure file from azure library
      - task: DownloadSecureFile@1
        inputs:
          secureFile: '.env-cmdrc.json'

      # Copy the .env file
      - task: CopyFiles@2
        inputs:
          sourceFolder: '$(Agent.TempDirectory)'
          contents: '**/*.env-cmdrc.json'
          targetFolder: '$(build.sourcesdirectory)'
          cleanTargetFolder: false

      
      - script: |
          npm run build-dev

- stage: qa
  jobs:
  - job: qa
    steps:
      - task: NodeTool@0
        inputs:
          versionSpec: '16.x'
        displayName: 'Install Node.js'


      # Download secure file from azure library
      - task: DownloadSecureFile@1
        inputs:
          secureFile: '.env-cmdrc.json'

      # Copy the .env file
      - task: CopyFiles@2
        inputs:
          sourceFolder: '$(Agent.TempDirectory)'
          contents: '**/*.env-cmdrc.json'
          targetFolder: '$(build.sourcesdirectory)'
          cleanTargetFolder: false

      
      - script: |
          npm run build-qa

....
```

**Note:** You need to copy the .env-cmdrc.json file to the same path as the package.json.

If you want to pass the pipeline variable to replace the value in  .env-cmdrc file, you can use the [File transform task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/file-transform-v2?view=azure-pipelines). Here is an example: [How to setup devops for build-once, but for multiple environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77745131/how-to-setup-devops-for-build-once-but-for-multiple-environments/77745701#77745701)

Comment: Thanks a ton for the detailed explaination. my main issue to manage multiple environments is addressed.